# Можно ли при включении сервера CentOS выполнить команду? Как?

Tags: сервер, centos, gnu-screen

Я в CentOS 7 в Ubuntu и в других системах не гуру, начил недавно, и уменя появился вопрос.
Может ли сервер CentOS 7 при включении выполнить команду, например screen? И как так зделать?

Comment: Например зачем вам screen при включении сервера?

Comment: Что бы влючать игровой сервер

Comment: Сервер cs 1.6, ну это не важно

Comment: Я зделал bash файл в нём написал скрипт который вкл сервер cs 1.6, но мне надо чтоб при вкл centos запускался этот bash скрипт, я знаю что можно через systemctl, но уменя не получается.

Comment: Вроде в centos используют systemd, так что вам нужно создать юнит для него.

Comment: Я создал, но при тестировании, пишет что Infalid arguments

Comment: Сейчас отправлю сам код юнита

Comment: Вот код юнита. https://pastebin.com/KS6BKme1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=rc.local+screen // возможно, понадобится [включить rc-local.service](https://www.cipheronic.com/rc-local-service-enabling-on-centos7/): `$ sudo systemctl enable rc-local`

Comment: `@reboot root /usr/bin/screen...` в кроне задание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в автостарт закинуть. Единственное придется писать скрипт на bash если это 6 версия и закидывать в /etc/init.d, а в Centos/RHEL/OEL-7 это уже через systemctl.
Тут для 7-ой версии
https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/255845/

Answer (score 0):

думаю самый простой вариант, чтобы на заморачиваться с написанием скриптов загрузки /etc/rc.d/init.d,

в файл:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

прописываешь что тебе нужно
потом делаешь:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

как написано у него внутри.